# Looking for Class Name of Google Chrome on Android Tablet

Tags: android, google-chrome, classname

I am working on an XML file that will change some settings on start up, including which apps will be displayed.
[image]

I am trying to have the only app displayed be Google Chrome but I can't seem to find the Class Name for the app.

I have tried to a few different things such as having the class name be the same as the package name but it doesn't seem to work. I have also tried to find another solution somewhere online but I can't seem to get a straight answer.

Does anyone know how I can find Google Chrome's Class Name, for an Android tablet?

I am newer to this type of thing, so any information is helpful!